# WinInet upload file

Tags: c++, http, winapi, wininet

I wrote a C++ function to perform uploading file using WinInet Library. The code is compiled and executed without returning error, but I can't handle the file in the server side. Both the php and the python server don't recognize file.
Here is the code :

```
#define DEFAULT_USERAGENT "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1" 
#define MY_HOST "192.168.1.101"
#define ALT_HTTP_PORT 8080
#define METHOD_POST "POST"
#define BUFSIZE 1024

void UploadFile()
{
    char szHeaders[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------974767299852498929531610575";
    char szContent[] = "---------------------------974767299852498929531610575\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"main.cpp\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    char szEndData[] = "\r\n---------------------------974767299852498929531610575--\r\n";
    unsigned char c;
    char szBuffer[BUFSIZE];
    memset(szBuffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
    char* szData = NULL;
    DWORD dwBytes;
    HANDLE hIn = CreateFile("main.cpp", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    for(int i = 0; i < BUFSIZE - 1 ; i++){
        ReadFile(hIn, &c, 1, NULL, NULL);
        szBuffer[i] = c;
    }
    szBuffer[BUFSIZE - 1] = '\0';
    CloseHandle(hIn);
    size_t sDataSize = strlen(szBuffer) + strlen(szContent) + strlen(szEndData) + 1;
    szData = new char[sDataSize];
    SecureZeroMemory(szData, sizeof(szData));
    strcat(szData, szContent);
    strcat(szData, szBuffer);
    strcat(szData, szEndData);
    szData[sDataSize] = '\0';

    HINTERNET io = InternetOpen(DEFAULT_USERAGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(!io){
        std::cerr << "InternetOpen Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    HINTERNET ic = InternetConnect(io, MY_HOST, ALT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if(!ic){
        std::cerr << "InternetConnect Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    HINTERNET hreq = HttpOpenRequest(ic, METHOD_POST, "/upload", NULL,NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
    if(!hreq){
        std::cerr << "HttpOpenRequest Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    HttpSendRequest(hreq, szHeaders, strlen(szHeaders), szData, strlen(szData));
    InternetCloseHandle(io);
    InternetCloseHandle(ic);
    InternetCloseHandle(hreq);
    delete[] szData;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your MIME boundary lines in `szContent` and `szEndData` are wrong.  Read [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046).  A boundary line in the content data begins with two `-` characters, followed by the text specified in the `boundary` parameter of the `Content-Type` header (and in the case of an ending boundary line, then followed by two more `-` characters).

The boundary lines you are using in your content data are missing those two leading `-` characters. You have 27 leading dashes in the `boundary` header, so you need 29 leading dashes in the content, not 27 like you have.

Also, you are assuming the input file is exactly 1023 bytes in size.  But, more importantly, you are not doing any error handling on the `CreateFile()` call to make sure the file is actually open, or any error handling on the `ReadFile()` call to make sure data is actually being read in (hint: the 4th parameter *cannot* be NULL when the 5th parameter is NULL).

You are trying to read the entire file (well, up to 1023 bytes, anyway) into memory, and then send it.  At the very least, you should use `GetFileSize()` to get the actual file size, and then allocate `szData` accordingly and read directly into it. You don't need `szBuffer` at all.

There are other minor errors in your code, too.  Like misusing `sizeof()`, assuming that the file data does not contain any null bytes in it, leaking memory, etc.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#define DEFAULT_USERAGENT "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1" 
#define MY_HOST "192.168.1.101"
#define ALT_HTTP_PORT 8080
#define METHOD_POST "POST"

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct FileCloser
{
    typedef HANDLE pointer;

    void operator()(HANDLE h)
    {
        if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            CloseHandle(h);
    }
};

struct InetCloser
{
    typedef HINTERNET pointer;

    void operator()(HINTERNET h)
    {
        if (h != NULL)
            InternetCloseHandle(h);
    }
}; 

void UploadFile()
{
    const char *szHeaders = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----974767299852498929531610575";
    const char *szContent = "------974767299852498929531610575\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"main.cpp\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    const char *szEndData = "\r\n------974767299852498929531610575--\r\n";

    std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, FileCloser> hIn(CreateFile("main.cpp", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL));
    if (hIn.get() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cerr << "CreateFile Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hIn.get(), NULL);
    if (dwFileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        std::cerr << "GetFileSize Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    size_t sContentSize = strlen(szContent);
    size_t sEndDataSize = strlen(szEndData);

    std::vector<char> vBuffer(sContentSize + dwFileSize + sEndDataSize);
    char *szData = &vBuffer[0];

    memcpy(szData, szContent, sContentSize);
    szData += sContentSize;

    DWORD dw = 0, dwBytes;
    while (dw < dwFileSize)
    {
        if (!ReadFile(hIn.get(), szData, dwFileSize-dw, &dwBytes, NULL))
        {
            std::cerr << "ReadFile Error" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        szData += dwBytes;
        dw += dwBytes;
    }

    hIn.reset();

    memcpy(szData, szEndData, sEndDataSize);

    std::unique_ptr<HINTERNET, InetCloser> io(InternetOpen(DEFAULT_USERAGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0));
    if (io.get() == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "InternetOpen Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<HINTERNET, InetCloser> ic(InternetConnect(io.get(), MY_HOST, ALT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0));
    if (ic.get() == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "InternetConnect Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<HINTERNET, InetCloser> hreq(HttpOpenRequest(ic.get(), METHOD_POST, "/upload", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0));
    if (hreq.get() == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "HttpOpenRequest Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!HttpSendRequest(hreq.get(), szHeaders, -1, &vBuffer[0], vBuffer.size()))
        std::cerr << "HttpSendRequest Error" << std::endl;
}
```

An alternative option is to use `HttpSendRequestEx()` instead, so you can then use `InternetWriteFile()` in a loop to read+send the file in chunks on each loop iteration.  That way, you do not have to read the entire file into memory before sending:

```
#define DEFAULT_USERAGENT "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1" 
#define MY_HOST "192.168.1.101"
#define ALT_HTTP_PORT 8080
#define METHOD_POST "POST"
#define BUFSIZE 1024
    
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

struct FileCloser
{
    typedef HANDLE pointer;

    void operator()(HANDLE h)
    {
        if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            CloseHandle(h);
    }
};

struct InetCloser
{
    typedef HINTERNET pointer;

    void operator()(HINTERNET h)
    {
        if (h != NULL)
            InternetCloseHandle(h);
    }
}; 

bool WriteToInternet(HINTERNET hInet, const void *Data, DWORD DataSize)
{
    const BYTE *pData = (const BYTE *) Data;
    DWORD dwBytes;

   while (DataSize > 0)
   {
       if (!InternetWriteFile(hInet, pData, DataSize, &dwBytes))
           return false;
       pData += dwBytes;
       DataSize -= dwBytes;
   }

   return true;
}

void UploadFile()
{
    const char *szHeaders = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----974767299852498929531610575";
    const char *szContent = "------974767299852498929531610575\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"main.cpp\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    const char *szEndData = "\r\n------974767299852498929531610575--\r\n";

    std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, FileCloser> hIn(CreateFile("main.cpp", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL));
    if (hIn.get() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cerr << "CreateFile Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hIn.get(), NULL);
    if (dwFileSize == INVALID_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        std::cerr << "GetFileSize Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<HINTERNET, InetCloser> io(InternetOpen(DEFAULT_USERAGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0));
    if (io.get() == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "InternetOpen Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<HINTERNET, InetCloser> ic(InternetConnect(io.get(), MY_HOST, ALT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0));
    if (ic.get() == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "InternetConnect Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<HINTERNET, InetCloser> hreq(HttpOpenRequest(ic.get(), METHOD_POST, "/upload", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0));
    if (hreq.get() == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "HttpOpenRequest Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!HttpAddRequestHeaders(hreq.get(), szHeaders, -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE | HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD))
    {
        std::cerr << "HttpAddRequestHeaders Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    } 

    size_t sContentSize = strlen(szContent);
    size_t sEndDataSize = strlen(szEndData);

    INTERNET_BUFFERS bufferIn = {};
    bufferIn.dwStructSize  = sizeof(INTERNET_BUFFERS);
    bufferIn.dwBufferTotal = sContentSize + dwFileSize + sEndDataSize;

    if (!HttpSendRequestEx(hreq.get(), &bufferIn, NULL, HSR_INITIATE, 0))
    {
        std::cerr << "HttpSendRequestEx Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!WriteToInternet(hreq.get(), szContent, sContentSize)))
    {
        std::cerr << "InternetWriteFile Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    char szData[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dw = 0, dwBytes;

    while (dw < dwFileSize)
    {
        if (!ReadFile(hIn.get(), szData, std::min(dwFileSize-dw, sizeof(szData)), &dwBytes, NULL))
        {
            std::cerr << "ReadFile Error" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        if (!WriteToInternet(hreq.get(), szData, dwBytes))
        {
            std::cerr << "InternetWriteFile Error" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        dw += dwBytes;
    }

    if (!WriteToInternet(hreq.get(), szEndData, sEndDataSize))
    {
        std::cerr << "InternetWriteFile Error" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!HttpEndRequest(hreq.get(), NULL, HSR_INITIATE, 0))
        std::cerr << "HttpEndRequest Error" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite szContent and szEndData, so I can well understand , and thank you

Comment: @YeniiCeri: what do you not understand exactly?  Whatever you specify in the `boundary` of the `Content-Type` header, simply precede it with `--` in each boundary line in the content data.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked for me after I wrote 14 previous versions that failed! I really appreciate this post!